# invalid memory alloc request size 1073741824

Tags: postgresql

I need to put a zip file in the database where the videos are stored. The file is 700 MB. I know that the allowed field size in postgres is 1gb. However, when I want to record the entire archive, I get an error

`out of memory DETAIL:  Cannot enlarge string buffer containing 0 bytes by 1469104433 more bytes.`

I decided that it might be better to split the archive roughly in half. and when downloading a 300mb file, I get the following error:

`invalid memory alloc request size 1073741824`

I use python for writing. The command looks like this

`"""INSERT INTO table1 (filename, exp_id) VALUES (%s, %s)"""`

exp_id - just a number (int)

P.S. I know that it is better to store links to files in the database, but in this case, storing a file in the database is a necessity, not my whim

`max_connections = 4 shared_buffers = 4GB work_mem = 1GB`

Comment: Your `filename` is 700MB in size? If you store a `bytea` in text form, it will have twice its original size and exceed the limit. You have to use binary mode or store it in chunks: `UPDATE tab SET bincol = bincol || $1 WHERE ...`. You may still run out of memory with a small database like that. You can also run OOM on the client.